# Validation outside the form

Tags: angularjs, validation

Say I have an html markup with some number of inputs. The `form` tag is absent (all communication is through REST services). I need to collect data from inputs and send async request.

I want to perform validation on those inputs (required, email, etc), IE8 should be supported.
How this can be done with angular?

Comment: if form tag is absent, you can check through Javascript or angular whether given input is valid or not on blur event of that particular input control.

Comment: Use `ng-form` just for validation, then communicate to your server through `ng-submit='submit()'`

Comment: You could us this module - http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/

Comment: @Raghav, `ng-form` is the way to go, thank you. Can you create an answer from your comment, so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Thank you @Kai for accepting my answer comment. I have created an answer from the comment. Mark it as accepted if you find helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm):  ngForm: Nestable alias of form directive. HTML does not allow nesting of form elements. It is useful to nest forms, for example if the validity of a sub-group of controls needs to be determined.

So just add this in your code:

```
<div ng-form="myForm">
    <div ng-class="{'has-error':myForm.name.$error.required && !myForm.name.$pristine}">
        <input type="text" name="name" required />
        <p ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required && !myForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">This field is required</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See angular validation in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eZWqCJak5bhsAYV6Iqe8?p=preview